# Oracle Text Query over Hundreds of Keywords

Tags: sql, contains, oracle-text

Oracle Text is great. But now I have to query with over 100 words that are stored in a separate table (let's say table_keywords). Do anybody know how to do that without writing all keywords into the query?

**Instead of**

```
Select a_id, text from xy where 
contains(text, 'x')>0 or
contains(text, 'x1')>0 or 
contains(text, 'x2')>0 or 
etc.
```

**Do**

```
Select a_id, text from xy where contains(text, table_keywords)>0
```

Is sth. like that possible?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would first try this with a `join` or something similar.  Does this work?

```
select a_id, text
from xy
where exists (select 1
              from keywords kw
              where contains(xy.text, kw.word) > 0
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

The hint with join was gold!

Solution

```
Select a_id, text from xy
    inner join keywords kw on contains(xy.text, kw.word)>0
```